# OpenGL UV coords are broken if I draw more than one quad

Tags: java, opengl, bitmap, rendering, lwjgl

Im trying to implement Bitmap font rendering. The only thing that confuses me so much, that i have to ask about it here, is that when I draw the quads for each char, every time it a new quad get rendered, the UV`s are absolutelly broken.
If I just render a single quad, everything is OK.

(tile x = 3, y = 4)

[image]

Thats what it looks like with a few more letters.
[image]

Thats my code to render this stuff:

```
...
    rc.translate(getTransform().getPos());
    drawTileAt(3, 4);
    rc.translate(100, 0, 0);
    drawTileAt(5, 5);
    rc.translate(200, 0, 0);
    drawTileAt(2,6);
    rc.translate(300,0,0);
    drawTileAt(1, 7);
...

public void drawTileAt(int x, int y)
{
    float w = 1f / 16f;
    float _x = 1f / 16f * x;
    float _y = 1f / 16f * y;
    GL11.glBegin(GL11.GL_QUADS);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 100);GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x,_y);
    GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x + w,_y);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100,0);GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x + w,_y + w);
    GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
    GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x,_y + w);
    GL11.glEnd();
}
```

Im also drawing VBO quads with tex-coords, everything looks fine...

Answer (score 5):

`glVertex()` bundles up the current vertex state (like the texture coordinate!) and sends it to the GPU.

So you need to set the texcoord *before* you set the vertex position:

```
GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x,_y);         GL11.glVertex2f(0, 100);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x + w,_y);     GL11.glVertex2f(0, 0);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x + w,_y + w); GL11.glVertex2f(100,0);
GL11.glTexCoord2f(_x,_y + w);     GL11.glVertex2f(100, 100);
```

Comment: Well, I have tried everything except that. Anyway, thank you mate, that solved the problem :)